# How can I save/append text from one textbox to another textbox on the same Form in VB

Tags: vb.net, text, textbox, save, append

Basically what I'm trying to figure out how to do is save text from one textbox to another textbox on the same form. I see a lot of post on how to save or store text from one textbox to another on a different form but not any with doing that on the same form.

I'm currently working on a feature in my program that allows me to with a click fn my "LogItLater" button save the fields from the First Name, Last Name, and Phone# textboxes on my form and place them on a different textbox on my form which allows the user to add more or edit that information at later time.

I'm doing this in VB so just a simple how to would be great, this is my first time asking a question so I hope I was as specific as possible.

---

So my new issue is this when I add more than one statement like this

```
txtScrapeBox.Text = txtFirstName.Text
txtScrapeBox.Text = txtLastName.Text
txtScrapeBox.Text = txtPhone.Text
```

The only text that is saved is the last statement and in this case it is the txtPhone.Text, will I need a condition statement to get the first two to save as well?

Comment: `TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text`  it will be the same as the one form to another situation you mention, just without the other form reference

Comment: Hey Plutonix Thanks For the response, I used the technique suggested and the problem I run into is that when I click the "LogitLater" button the Text from the First Name box for instance disappears but does not show in the textbox that I want it to. Im sure it is saving but I guess im missing some more code that shows the text while the form is running.

Comment: perhaps you could [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23855753/edit) your post to include some code.  My crystal ball is on holiday.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: code does not format in comments.  that was why I said [Edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23855753/edit) and even provided a link for you to [Edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23855753/edit)

Comment: thanks for the posting pointers I just edited my post for my new question I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the last assignment is retained, because you are replacing the contents with each assignment.  To append (I am assuming this is a multiline TB - if it isnt, the data will come out: `ZiggyWagner(800)5550195`):

```
txtScrapeBox.Text = txtFirstName.Text & Environment.NewLine & _
        txtLastName.Text & Environment.NewLine & txtPhone.Text
```

This presents a problem down the road - if they want to edit "LastName", how will you know which line they want to edit?  You will have to save all three items to `txtScrapeBox` in the same order every time and fetch them back using the `.Lines()` property.

Another way might be to save them to a `ListBox` where item 0 is always first name, item 1 = LastName etc:

```
 lbData.Items.Clear          ' remove previous contents
 lbData.Items.Add(txtFirstName.Text)
 lbData.Items.Add(txtLastName.Text)
 lbData.Items.Add(txtPhone.Text)
```

Get one back to edit:

```
 txtFirstName.Text = lbData.Items(0).ToString
 ' or
 If lbData.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then      ' check if they selected one
     txtFirstName.Text = lbData.SelectedItem.ToString
 End If
```

Comment: added a bit for getting stuff back if you end up using a listbox.